# Entity Framework dbContext is disposed too early

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6

I am trying to make my code work with Dependency Injection but I am having a few issues.

I have the following code which fetches a User and the associated Roles.

```
public virtual User GetUser(string username,string password,evolutiondbEntities context, IUserRole userRoleRepository)
        {
            User systemUser = new User();
            using(context)
            {
                systemUser = (from u in context.Users where u.Username == username && u.UserPassword == password select u).FirstOrDefault();
                List<IUserRole> roleList = userRoleRepository.GetRoles(systemUser.UserID);
                systemUser._roles = roleList;
            }

            return systemUser;
        }
```

The code for the GetRoles Method is as follows

```
public List<IUserRole> GetRoles(string userID,evolutiondbEntities context)
        {
            List<IUserRole> roleList = new List<IUserRole>();
            using(context)
            {
                roleList = (from r in context.UserRoles where r.UserID == userID select r).ToList<IUserRole>();
            }

            return roleList;
        }
```

The code fetches the user correctly but then when it calls the GetRoles() method the context appears to have been disposed and so therefore fails.

NOTE: I know I should be passing in an interface for the context but I have not got that far yet.

Comment: You should inject the context into your service and use it without `using` block as at the end of `using` block the context is disposed.

Comment: Would I then use a using block at the point of injection? I thought the using block was recommended as it makes sure the connection is closed after operations?

Comment: The ioc container will dispose of the context when it's appropriate (at the end of the request)

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin is correct. A `using` block will always dispose of its object at the end of the block, so when you have IoC, don't wrap DbContext in any `using` blocks.

Comment: Vsevolod Goloviznin, if you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inject the context into your service and use it without `using` block as at the end of `using` block the context is disposed. You IoC container is responsible for instantiating and disposing of the created objects as you instruct it.

So you will typically have this:

IoC registration:

```
container.For<Context>().Use<Context>();
```

And in you service:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly IUserRole _userRoleRepository;
    public SomeService(Context context, IUserRole userRoleRepository)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userRoleRepository = userRoleRepository;
    }

    public virtual User GetUser(string username, string password)
    {
        User systemUser = new User();         
        systemUser = (from u in _context.Users where u.Username == username && u.UserPassword == password select u).FirstOrDefault();
        List<IUserRole> roleList = _userRoleRepository.GetRoles(systemUser.UserID);
        systemUser._roles = roleList;          

        return systemUser;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past, using Ninject. If your not using Ninject then your IoC will most likely have something similar.

Under Ninjects binding for the context i had to use the .InRequestScope() method.

```
kernel.Bind<EmployeeDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```